# How to clear the post data for a textbox in an ASP.NET MVC application?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

By default, a textbox rendered using <%= Html.TextBox("somefield")%> uses the value from the post data, e.g. if you have validation errors on your page, the value is retrieved from the posted data and used for the value attribute.

Now, in a few cases I want to be able to clear that value, in other words I want the textbox to be blank, I don't want MVC to get the value from the posted data and uses it for the value attribute, how can I do? How can I clear the post data?

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
ModelState.Remove("key");
```

Comment: This also seems to work if you want to clear all the values: ModelState.Clear();

Comment: Any way to do it without clearing the querystring and validation errors?

Comment: @StuartDobson For future reference, if you remove the key then set your validation error, that shouldn't be a problem. At least, it worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the value from the model state, like this:

```
ViewData.ModelState.Remove("somefield");
```

Answer (score 3):

I found I had to both remove the ModelState and change the model, as if MVC tries ModelState first, then the model:

```
ModelState.Remove("key");
model.key = "";
```

And if you don't want to lose your Error state for the model, you can just change the value like this:

```
ModelState.SetModelValue("Captcha", new ValueProviderResult(null, string.Empty, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
model.key = "";
```