# how to clear the text

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

ASP.Net MVC 3 and Razor
I submit the page using the following code

```
       <input name ="button" type="submit" value="AddData" />
```

I read the Modal data inside the control action method from the server side.

The data I read is from the below code

@Html.TextAreaFor(m => m.Letter.Letters, new {id = "LetterTextArea"});

I am not able to clear the text in the text box after submitting the page.

How to clear the text after submitting(clicking the button) the data.

Thank you,
Smith

Comment: possibile duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1575813/how-to-clear-the-post-data-for-a-textbox-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application

Answer (score 2):

I think your are returning the same Model to the View back. You should instead do a Redirect to the **GET** Action  ([Post -Redirect- Get Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get))

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Add(UserViewModel model)
{
  if(ModelState.IsValid)
  {
    //Save the data, If everything is ok, We will do a Redirect to GET action
    return RedirectToAction("Add","User");
  } 
  return View(model);    
}
```

[`RedirectToAction`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller.redirecttoaction%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method will issue a `GET` request and hit your GET action method which returns the empty form.

```
public ActionResult Add()
{
  var userViewModel=new UserViewModel();
  return View(userViewModel);
}
```

[Here](http://devlicio.us/blogs/tim_barcz/archive/2008/08/22/prg-pattern-in-the-asp-net-mvc-framework.aspx) is a good tutorial why you should consider PRG pattern.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Shyju answer which is the best practice in this situation you could remove the value from ModelState because HTML helpers will first use the value that's stored inside ModelState and after that in your model:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SomeAction(MyViewModel model)
{
    ModelState.Remove(Letter.Letters);
    model.Letter.Letters = "";
    return View(model);
}
```